# Enforce iframe to open its links inside the frame

Tags: html, iframe, xhtml, window, frame

Is there a way to enforce iframe to open its **target="_blank"** links inside the frame and not open a new window/browser-tab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a bit of JavaScript, made easier using a framework such as jquery, that just removes that attribute from each link on the page. Does that suffice?

**UPDATE**: OK, so following your clarification, and having done a quick test, I believe the answer is "no". You'll get a permission denied error when trying to access the iframe's document via javascript.

Comment: I can use jQuery, but I have to mention of course that I have no access to the frame's source-code as it's not my website.

Comment: Depending on your needs, Dom access is fine. Do you just want this to work for YOU, or for everyone? If you want it to work for others, and it's not your site, that's a bit of a moral conflict.

Comment: I want this to work for every user of the website who view the page with the frame.

Comment: So your page is loading into an external frameset that you have no control over?

Comment: @CheckRaise No, my page is loading an external page via frame, and I don't want the frame to open links with a _target="blank"_ attribute in a new window/tab. I want these links to open in the same frame.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, did you ever figure this out?